# How to clear an image field in django forms?

Tags: django, django-forms

So my views look like this:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','content','image', 'status']
```

The image field currently looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to have like a button to clear the image from the field? The only way to remove the image is to do it from django admin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html file add a button with an id:

```
<button id="clear">Clear image </button>
```

Then in your html, add

```
{% load static %}

<script>
document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("image").value = "";
}, false);
</script>
```

**Note** that you need to use your chrome developor tool to find out what is the id of your file input field, in the above example, I used "image", but it most likely be different. You need to change `get.ElementById("image")` with the id of your file input field.

Comment: I am using crispy forms, so all I have got in my HTML is `{{ form|crispy }}`. Any other way to get this to work?

Comment: sure thing. open your chrome developer tools, go through each element, and see what is the id of file input. add button just before the form.